# Removing blank space at bottom of dialog list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

[image]

I have it when you open the dialog window, there is this blank space below the 5 options... inside of the DumpView Hierarchy in Eclipse, It says it is (2) FrameLayout [34,894][686,1022].

My code is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.sync_frequency);
                    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
                    String[] syncOptions = mSyncOptions;
                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, android.R.id.text1, syncOptions);
                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(modeAdapter, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Position is " + selectedPosition);

                        }
                    });
                    builder.setView(listView);
                    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.sync_cancel,null);
                    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    dialog.show();
```

im trying to get rid of the blank space there... Im not sure how to get rid of it...
I even tried `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

But it doesn't cut off the space. I guess cause it sees it as a framlayout and not blank space. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting layout params to listView (before inflating to dialog)?

```
ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
listView.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
.
.
.
builder.setView(listView);
```

Another option is to not use setView on dialog but rather setAdapter() as in below example:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.sync_frequency);
    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
    String[] syncOptions = mSyncOptions;
    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, android.R.id.text1, syncOptions);
    builder.setAdapter(modeAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.sync_cancel,null);
    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: It worked with the second section you showed! Thanks!
How would I get which item is selected when they click?
I used int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition(); when I used the view, and it returned the item number selected. How would i get itwith the adapter? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, switch case with int which works. Thanks again! it was driving me crazy.

Comment: int which is your selected item :) it shows the position inside your syncOptions array as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

This only occurs on API level 10+ devices.

To use the old dialog theme that didn't have those space issues initialize your AlertDialog.Builder like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
```

Comment: ...except that clashes with the decor used in the rest of the app running on 10+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded in removing the extra space on the end of the AlertDialog list by ignoring its setAdapter() entirely.

I create a ListView, and set the Adapter and OnListItemClickListener directly on that, before calling builder.setView() with it.

I have no real idea why this works, so it may break on other devices - hopefully not catastrophically.